# In magento after migration from 1.7 to 1.9 changing in user password changing is not working

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7, magento-1.9.1

I have migrated my magneto site from 1.7 to 1.9 and now I am changing user password going through the admin>>system>>permission>>user it is not working. I am seeing the password filed is getting changed in database but when I am trying to login using info I am getting "Invalid user name and password"

Thanks in advance.
mrphpguru

Comment: What have you tried?  Have you cleared caches/rebuilt indexes/[recompiled](http://alanstorm.com/magento_compiler_path)?

Comment: Notice to others, this question is duplicated on http://magento.stackexchange.com/q/35771/3408

Comment: I have the same problem, I've also migrated from 1.7 to 1.9

Comment: Have you tried to set the password manually with mysql? This works for me. But of course, is only a workaround.  Here you will find a guide for that: http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/recover/resetting-admin-password